# Incomplete OpenCSV import

Tags: java, file, servlets, opencsv

I tried importing the records from a CSV file using OpenCSV. I observed that OpenCSV was actually missing out some of the entries in the last row of my file. The code is as below. I know that I can do a writeAll operation. But i need individual rows for some other operations. The number of records are around 56000 in my file.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile))));

CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(path2+File.separator+fileName)))), ',');

List<String[]> fileContents = new ArrayList<String[]>();
fileContents = reader.readAll();
for(int i=0; i<fileContents.size(); i++){
    String[] row = fileContents.get(i);
writer.writeNext(row);
```

Comment: Instead of `new File(path2+File.separator+fileName)` use `new File(path2, fileName)`. That way you can't forget to add the separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the error. I wasnt closing the writer.
 writer.close();
And the file was completely written. Don't know why it doesnt complete writing the file otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem as described by Abhiroop when using `StatefulBeanToCsv<T> beanWriter`. Thanks for documenting the error with `writer.close`!

Since a Writer implements `Closeable` which extends `AutoCloseable`, it should be wrapped in a try-with-resources as shown below.

For me, the advantage of `StatefulBeanToCsv` is that it can be used with a `MappingStrategy<T>`.

```java
public void exportToCsv(List<T> beans) {
    try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(FILE_PATH_NAME)) {
        final StatefulBeanToCsv<T> beanWriter = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<T>(printWriter).build();
        beanWriter.write(beans);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("export failed", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if prior to the missing values, one of the values has a comma inside (i.e. "this is a csv value, with a comma inside it").

Comment: No there arent any commas in any of the contents. Actually I'm trying to split these entries into smaller files of 10000 entries each. But some entries get missed in each smaller file in the last row.

Comment: are there any other escape characters (such as , ' " etc.) in the values prior to the missing values?
i had a similar problem in the past, and it turned out the values in the csv files contained escape characters, that the opencsv didn't handle well.

Comment: There are only words. Even if it were to exist, y does it not write only the last row properly? I find it peculiar.

Comment: do you have a header row? in that case, the fileContents.size() value for the index, is 1 row short.